# VBA Excel find and replace WITHOUT replacing items already replaced

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to make an excel script that can find and replace data, but for the love of everything I cannot figure out how to write it.

Situation:

> A-----------B-----------C
>
> Cat-------Dog------Banana
>
> Dog------Fish------Apple
>
> Fish------Cat-------Orange

So the macro would look at the data in a cell in column B, then look at the adjacent cell in column C, and replace all instances of that data in column A with what if found in C. So the results would be:

> A---------------B-----------C
>
> Orange------Dog------Banana
>
> Banana------Fish------Apple
>
> Apple--------Cat-------Orange

But that's not all, I would like it to not change cells in A that already have been changed once! (I'm trying this with changing the background colour)

Any help? I am at a complete loss.

EDIT:

Okay I found out how to do the easy part (replacing), but I cannot find out how to not change cells that already have been changed once. Here is my code:

```
Sub multiFindNReplace()
    Dim myList, myRange
    Set myList = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:B3") 'two column range where find/replace pairs are
    Set myRange = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D2:D5") 'range to be searched
    For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
    myRange.Replace what:=cel.Value, replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, ReplaceFormat:=True
    Next cel
End Sub
```

As far as I can tell,     ReplaceFormat:=True
doesn't do anything ;/ so items that already have been replaced once still are being replaced! Is there a way to somehow make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer using your recommendation with color as a one-time limiter:

```
Sub Replace_Once()

'Find last row using last cell in Column B
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Clear colors in Column A
Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

'Look at each cell in Column B one at a time (Cel is a variable)
For Each Cel In Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    'Compare the cell in Column B with the Value in Column A one at a time (C is a variable)
    For Each C In Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
        'Check if the Cell in Column A matches the Cell in Column B and sees if the color has changed.
        If C.Value = Cel.Value And C.Interior.Color <> RGB(200, 200, 200) Then
            'Colors the cell
            C.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
            'Updates the value in Column A with the cell to the right of the Cell in Column B
            C.Value = Cel.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
Next

'Uncomment the line below to remove color again
'Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still new to VBA so I'm having trouble understanding this code. Which row is being changed and which rows are being used to alter that row?

Comment: Is the code clear now? You could also test it by walking through each line by pressing F8 repetitively and watch what is happening.

Comment: That is really great! For some reason the Range ("B1:B" & LastRow) does not seem to work. When I change it to a specific range it works like a charm, but when it uses LastRow it does not seem to work.

EDIT: figured out why, when column B is not the same length as A, it will not apply the macro to the part of column A that is longer than B. Is it possible to circumvent this?

Comment: @LeMarcin when you step through the code using `F8` key, what is the value of `lastRow` after it's assignment?

Comment: It's whatever the length is of column B (in my testing 264, and column A is 3650 [allot of duplicate items])
EDIT: Oh right, I just realized that I can change this my making     LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row work with A instead of B

Comment: Yes, I'm glad you got that figured out. To use Column A for last row. Use LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Something has come up, when I use a large file I get the following runtime error: "method 'color' of object 'interior' failed". Any suggestions why this could be happening?